# Jhipster - POST method converted to GET while enabling both HTTP & HTTPS

Tags: https, jhipster

Jhipster version 3.2.3 - POST method converted to GET while enabling both HTTP redirect & HTTPS with the 405 error.

"type": "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
    "title": "Method Not Allowed",
    "status": 405,
    "detail": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/api/registers",
    "message": "error.http.405"

Comment: See if there are options to change the redirect status code. It'll be emitting a 302/303 and you want it to emit a 307 - see [Http Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, when server redirects client through a 302 status code, it's the client's responsibility to handle it and the default behavior is to do a GET on new location which is safe as you may not want to post your data to an unknown URL, so it's up to the angular developer to code a different behavior in the angular service and probably using HttpClient interceptor